# Multiple file upload buttons on the same page for different posts

Tags: jquery, html

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. I have a bulletin page where a user can post a bulletin for everyone to see. Once a bulletin gets posted, the user has the option of attaching any type of file that they want other users to see/download. Right now, the upload will only work if I start from the latest posted bulletin message. So the second bulletin upload won't work unless I upload to the first bulletin.

I'm not sure why this is happening.

[image] 
[Above is a sample of what the bulletins look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsB7E.jpg)

Here's my jquery:

```
    $('.attachment_upload').on('click', '#upload', function(){
     bulletin_id = $('input[id^="bulletin_value"]').val();
        alert(bulletin_id);
        $('#attachment').fileupload({
            url:'/phplib/upload_file.php',
            multipart: true,
            type: "POST",
            formData: {
                table: 'bulletin',
                field: 'id',
                id: bulletin_id
            },
        });

            if($('#attachment')[0] !== undefined){
                $('#attachment').fileupload('send', {files: $('#attachment')[0].files})
                .success(function(result, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(result);

                    apprise("<p style='text-align: center; color: green '>Uploaded successfully. Reloading page... <br><br><img src='/images/ajax-loader.gif' /></p>");
                    window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 1500); //reloads after 1 second
                    $('#zoom_close').trigger('click');
                }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);

                    apprise("<p style='text-align: center; ' class='error'>Upload failed. Reloading page... <br><br><img src='/images/ajax-loader.gif' /></p>");
                    //window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 1500); //reloads after 1 second
                    //$( "<b>Upload failed.</b>" ).appendTo('.error');
                });
            }
});
```

HTML:

```
            <h3>Attachments:</h3>

            <p class='attachment_upload bulletin_comment' id='{{bulletin.id}}'>

            <input type='file' multiple='multiple' name='attachment[]' id='attachment'><input type='hidden' id='bulletin_value' value='{{bulletin.id}}' /></input>

            <input type='button' id='upload' value='Upload'></input><label class='error'></label>

            <p class="help-block">Hold the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key to select multiple files.</p>
            <!--<span class='error'></span>-->
            </p>
```

Currently when I click upload on the second bulletin, it alerts me with the value of the first bulletin (which is the id for the attachment to get linked to that bulletin in the table)

Comment: I assume you output the HTML in a loop? You're only allowed to have one id per page, Jquery will always use the first one in the page.

Comment: check if the id is being repeated

Comment: @Fels Yea outputting in a loop. So what should I do ?

Comment: @loganSarav Look at the comment above you. Thats what I'm doing. But I  just changed everything to a class and thats still not working.

Comment: instead of class try using unique id, like attachment+bulletin id. So that upload has individual ids and will work

Comment: @loganSarav Sorry I'm confused, do you mean set the id of input type='file' to id='attachment{{bulletin.id}} ? Can you show me an example.

Comment: `{{bulletin.id}}` What format this is?

Comment: @Siva.G Twig templating engine. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html

Comment: yes add the bulletin id with the file upload id and see the whether the bulletin id is attached like this `attachment56`